# VBA to search the external data table for a record

Tags: vba, visio

I have linked to external data in Visio 2013 and have four different tabs/tables. When a user double clicks a shape the text of that shape will be used to search for a record inthe tables. Note that this data is not linked in the Visio linked data method. Just need to search the table manually not rely on some link between the data record and the shape that is pre-existing. 
External data is imported fine. I can capture the text of the double clicked shape. If you can tell me how to run a query against the external data that has been pulled into Visio then HIGHLIGHT the row. 
Thank You

Comment: Please provide more tecnical information, like screens, code, data, etc...

Comment: how did you get this external data *into* visio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the information regarding the data source (such as server/database name, credentials, etc.), you just need a few lines of VBA in a module like so:

```
Dim theVariableForDataFieldYouWant as Integer
Dim db as database
Dim rs as recordset
Set db = YourDataConnectionStringHere
Dim sql as string
sql = "Select aFieldYouWant, anotherFieldYouWant from yourTableName WHERE someField = yourCriteria"
set rs = db.openRecordSet(sql)

if rs.eof then
' you recordset is empty, nothing matched
else
theVariableForDataFieldYouWant = rs.fields("theDataField")
end if

rs.close
db.close
set rs = nothing
set db = nothing
```

If you provide a bit more detail, I can be more precise, but basically that sums it up. Put the code into a function or sub, then call it on your selected event.